# In R: Repeats in Dataframes are Causing Returns to Change

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that I am trying to pull from to create a new dataframe.

```
DF1                                       DF2
ClaimID    Money     Type                 ClaimID     Money    Type
1           500    "Weather"              1            500     "Non-Weather"
1           200    "Weather"              1            200     "Non-Weather"
2           50     "Non-Weather"          2            50      "Non-Weather"
```

Using this code:

```
DF3<-data.frame("ClaimID" = DF1$ClaimID, "FinalType" =
DF1$Type,"OldType" = DF2$Type)
```

With this code, adding a new column to show whether the "FinalType" and "OldType" agree:

```
DF3<-cbind(DF3, Agreement =c(ifelse(DF3$OldType == 
DF3$FinalType, "Agree","Disagree")))
```

I EXCPECT to create this dataframe:

```
DF3
ClaimID    FinalType    OldType       Agreement
1          Weather      Non-Weather   Disagree
1          Weather      Non-Weather   Disagree
2          Non-Weather  Non-Weather   Agree
```

However, I am getting:

```
DF3
ClaimID    FinalType    OldType       Agreement
1          Weather      Non-Weather   Disagree
1          Weather      weather       Agree
2          Non-Weather  Non-Weather   Agree
```

So, somehow it is changing the Type in DF2, even though in DF2, the type remains the same. Thank you

Comment: Can you please include a complete example which produces the bad output? When I build the tables and run your code as provided I get your expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what exactly you want. I can put in my exact codes but I do not think they would help to recreate without making the question very complex. The dataframes are about 20,000 obs long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a simplified example of what you want.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    claim = c(1, 1, 2),
    type1 = c("w", "w", "n"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df2 <- data.frame(
    claim = c(1, 1, 2),
    type2 = c("n", "n", "n"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df <- cbind(df1, df2$type2)
df$test <- df$type1 == df$type2
```

Note that with R it's better practice to use code of the form `a == b` rather than `ifelse` to test (element-wise) whether two vectors are equal.

In general, be careful when using `cbind`!  More often you will want to use `merge` to combine dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a faster solution using [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) join:

```
# using data.table
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# doing computation during joining, super fast and efficient
df1[df2, on = c('ClaimID', 'Money'), result := ifelse(Type != i.Type, 'Disagree','Agree')]
```